# Make DIVs match browser height

Tags: css, html, height

I have 3 < div > elements stacked on top of each other on screen.

```
   <div id="header"></div>
  <div id="content" style="height:900px;width:1400px; "></div>
  <div id="footer"></div>
```

I need to keep stated exact size of central DIV and I need 'header' and 'footer' to fill the space (remaining from 'content' height) on top and on the bottom equally, so all three DIVs would occupy exact window height.

Also I'd like header and footer have set  some minimum height  (so if screen becomes too small, these DIVs would keep some height, keep showing their contents, and scroller appears).

I can possibly do int in JS but CSS must be possible. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use `height:100%` for all three divs and `min-height` for whichever divs you need it for

Comment: @adaam, each div became 100%, so I now have them occupying 300% of window, that is not what I'd need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it quite easily in JS with jQuery using the following javascript code:

```
var spaceHeight = $(window).height()-$("#content").height();
$("#header, #footer").css('height', spaceHeight/2);
```

You should put that code somewhere where you will make sure to call it in case the layout changes or in $(document).ready() if the page layout will be static.

And in order to preserve the minimum heights of `#footer` and `#header` use the min-height properties in CSS.

Here's and example: http://jsfiddle.net/4h5f8/17/

Comment: Thanks a lot! I myself also came to conclusion that JS is the best way to directly control these heights, as I would like them equal. I fire this code onLoad and onResize that pretty much sums up the likely usage. One thing I didnt get, sometimes spaceHeight+content.height!=window height (yes, after this exact calculation!), difference is 0 to several pixels, changes with resizing. I wonder what causes this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code and see if it is what you need:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
#header {
    min-height:50px;
    height:10%;
    background-color:grey;
}
#content {
    height:80%;
    background-color:#EEEEEE;
}
#footer {
    min-height:50px;
    height:10%;
    background-color:grey;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="header"></div>
<div id="content"></div>
<div id="footer"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: To make this work, add a doctype, and add `html, body { height:100% }`